# Can I cook Meringue on tin foil rather than Baking paper?

Tags: baking, meringue

I am making meringue's and don't have access to baking paper, would tin foil work or could I just grease the tin itself?

Answer (score 5):

[Joy of Baking](http://www.joyofbaking.com/MeringueCookies.html) actually recommends using parchment *or* foil:

> ... it is a good idea to use parchment paper or aluminum foil to line
>   your baking sheets, not wax paper, as the meringue will sometimes stick to wax paper.

According to [Living Strong:](http://www.livestrong.com/article/469858-substitute-for-parchment-paper-in-baking-meringue/)

> Next in line for substitutions similar to parchment paper comes
>   aluminum foil. The flexibility of the aluminum foil allows you to
>   easily lift the meringues off your baking sheet and gently peel them
>   away from the foil, individually rather than trying to scrape them off
>   the pan with a spatula or knife. Just like parchment paper and waxed
>   paper, aluminum foil cuts down cleaning time by eliminating
>   the need to scrub your baking sheet.

They also say that if you don't have foil, as a last alternative, you can try spraying the sheet with baking spray (the kind with flour in it), or spray with regular oil spray and then dust with sugar.